# Team city template missing

Tags: teamcity

I was going to reuse teamcity configuration to new environments. Looks like the configuration is based on a template, but actually there is no clickable link to teamplate and I can't find it in the root project. I was thinking that the template was deleted but team city doen't allow to remove templates which are used at least in one configuration

[image]

Could you advice why how is it possible to reach and reuse the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the sanpshot you pasted, your template is created in the root project. If you don't get a clickable link , you probably don;t have access to the root project

If you do have access to create target, you can copy the target to a new target. Templated settings are preserved when you copy over targets. You just need t change the target variables and if required any triggers or dependencies